# Надежный вызов ping6 из php

Tags: php, ping, ipv6

Для IPv4 есть Net_ping.

Для IPv6 получается только это:

```
$ipv6 = "";
exec("ping6  $ipv6", $output, $status);
print_r($output);
```

Но это же, сами понимаете, что получается, даже если сделать:  `escapeshellcmd($ipv6)`.

Вопрос: Есть какой-нибудь надежный метод пинговать IPv6 из PHP скрипта?

Comment: похоже только так http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-exec.php

Comment: «сами понимаете, что получается» — нет, не понимаем)

Comment: @andreymal shell injection

Comment: @etki если с escapeshellcmd, то где?

Comment: Впрочем, я в справке проглядел, что  escapeshellcmd не экранирует пробел. Но тогда есть упомянутый в ответе  escapeshellarg)

Comment: @andreymal экранирование, вопреки расхожему мнению, еще не гарантирует безопасность

Comment: @etki полную безопасность гарантирует только полностью лишённое питания устройство, да-да, я в курсе (и то если не упадёт на голову кому-нибудь)

Comment: Конкретно в этом случае, на первый взгляд, могут быть проблемы с разными кодировками и локалями

Comment: @andreymal я конкретно про передачу желаемых аргументов желаемому бинарнику. В нормальных языках то завернутый во что-нибудь вызов к execv* сисколлу, передающий аргументы массивом, как и положено, но здесь все немного сложней.

Comment: @etki таки да, но всё же «экранирование ... не гарантирует безопасность» — сильное заявление, к которому желательно прилагать какие-нибудь пруфы, особенно когда речь об escapeshellarg :)

Comment: @andreymal это надеяться на работоспособность функций экранирования по-детcки наивно https://www.google.ru/search?q=escapeshellarg+vulnerability https://www.google.ru/search?q=mysql_real_escape_string+vulnerability

Comment: @etki опять же, надеяться на полную безопасность подключенного к питанию устройства тоже по-детски наивно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вас смущает незавершаемость процесса - можете воспользоваться флагом `-c count`, чтобы ограничить число пинг-запросов.

```
ping6 -c 1 example.com
```

---

По поводу экранирования - нужно использовать [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.escapeshellarg.php), а не `escapeshellcmd`:

```
$cmd = 'ping6 -c1 ' . escapeshellarg($ipv6);
```

Это не серебрянная пуля, у функции есть масса низкоуровневых проблем:

- Заприваченный более 4х лет назад [баг](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65755).
- Не работает в Win. [баг 2009г.](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49446)
- Обработка локалей. [баг](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54391)
- Альтернативные шеллы. [баг](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61706)

Можно обезопасить себя(не специалист, никаких гарантий), предварительно ограничив возможные некорректные символы:

```
if (!preg_match('/\A[-_.@\pN\pL]+\z/ui', $ipv6)) throw new \Exception('Bad domain'); // \pN - числовые символы, \pL - буквенные
```

---

Можно также реализовать функцию пинга самостоятельно, через ICMP

```
function ping($host, $timeout = 1, $ipv6 = false) {
    /* ICMP ping packet with a pre-calculated checksum */
    $package = "\x08\x00\x7d\x4b\x00\x00\x00\x00PingHost";
    $socket  = socket_create($ipv6 ? AF_INET6 : AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 1);
    socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec' => $timeout, 'usec' => 0));
    socket_connect($socket, $host, null);
    $ts = microtime(true);
    socket_send($socket, $package, strLen($package), 0);
    if (socket_read($socket, 255)) {
        $result = microtime(true) - $ts;
    } else {
        $result = false;
    }
    socket_close($socket);
    return $result;
}
```

Использован [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16650339/2110496)

Comment: Меня интересует безопасность exec с полученными от пользователя данными в переменной ipv6.

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает `escapeshellarg($ipv6)`? Если вы где-то читали статью о уязвимости, связанной с ней, не могли бы Вы поделиться?

Comment: @GarfieldCat https://stackoverflow.com/a/21290406/1068283

Comment: @vp_arth чуть ли не первая ссылка из гугла https://gist.github.com/Zenexer/40d02da5e07f151adeaeeaa11af9ab36

Comment: Что за пакет передается, пытался расшифровать 08} 0000PingHost? соответствует ли пакет стандартному в утилите ping/ping6?